# Picture wrapped using minipage affects next page text

Tags: minipage, picins

I am new to LaTeX, with help of some other. I found the following LaTeX code to wrap a figure into a paragraph.

```
\pichskip{15pt}% Horizontal gap between picture and text
\parpic[l][b]{%
  \begin{minipage}{3 in}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Capture.png}%
    \captionof{figure}{A DPPC bilayer embedded with polyalanine}
  \end{minipage}
}
```

Output of this code looks like the following, which clearly affects the text in next page. I don't want it. I want `minipage` to not to affect next page formatting. How to resolve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Presumably you are using wrapfig.  Add \WFclear at the end of the page.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Well, it's works with wrapfig but I don't want to use wrapfig. I use picins package, which trims a lot of unnecessary whitespace. Is there any option available for picins package ?

Comment: Sorry,  Mein verlessen ist sehr schlecht.  But I do know how to get rid of the extra space with wrapfig.